# How to increase bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I put a 50 rep bounty on [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28044/short-story-about-alien-military-telepathy) question but frankly it's driving me insane. I'm happy to increase the amount (to gain more attention) and I don't want to wait until it 'times out' in four days.

Is there a way to **increase** a bounty on a question that I've *already* added a bounty to?

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot change the amount of the bounty.

Moderators can revoke a bounty. They might be willing to do that if you pledge to put a higher bounty. However doing this after 3 days is somewhat unfair as the new bounty would be active for a week, not the remaining 4 days. Moderators could also decide not to take the risk that you won't set the bounty again, or decide that it's too much hassle.

Putting a higher bounty hardly attracts more attention anyway. Leave the 50 rep bounty for a week, and if nobody answers, put a 100 bounty for another week. You'll get more attention this way. If somebody answers during the first week and you really like the answer, you can reward that answer with another bounty after the fact.

Also consider that maybe nobody on the site has read this story, in which case all your bounties are in vain. Try to advertise or ask in other places, and report back if you found the answer. For example, you could post a [YASID](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!search/rec.arts.sf.written%2420yasid/rec.arts.sf.written/op34UGkc6x4/At4uLg28PY8J) on the Usenet group rec.arts.sf.written.

Comment: "Putting a higher bounty hardly attracts more attention anyway" - Is there data to back this up? Personally, I have had cases where I dug hard on a question with 100 and especially more bounty where I know I wouldn't bother with just 50.

Comment: @DVK No, I don't have data. System-wise, a bounty has the same effect regardless of its amount: bump the question and list it in the `featured` tab. People may be inclined to dig harder, but the same people will see the question in lists.